# Postfix installed, by mail() in PHP not working

Tags: php, postfix

I have a new server. Just installed Postfix (`apt-get install mailutils`), and configured postfix as "Internet site". Works fine when I'm logged in as regular user on the command prompt and use `mail xx@domain.com` to send a mail. When I try sending mail via PHP, nothing happens. I tried `mail(xx@domain.com, subject, my test);`, but nothing is sent. When I look at `/var/log/mail.log`, nothing appears (though everything appears when sending from command line, without PHP).

When I didn't change my php.ini line

```
;sendmail_path =
```

nothing appears in the mail.log file.
When, to test, I added

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t
```

I get an error in my `/var/log/mail.log`, saying

```
fatal: Recipient addresses must be specified on the command line or via the -t option
```

(which seemed to be specified, according to me...?)

Any idea what could be causing this? How can I get my PHP to send mail?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by re-installing (a new version of) PHP. Since no postfix was installed when compiling the first time, the mail() was disabled...